# RequireJS with Angularjs for loading controllers on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading, amd

I have done a lot of research for requireJS AMD in AngularJS and found out that

> the 
>   JS files are being called by triggers either by changing url or
>   clicking a button

I have the home page which is divided into 5 sections with each one having its html and controller file.

> The motive is to call only the first section on page load with its
>   controller and html file. And load the rest files one by one as we scroll to the
>   bottom.

Is there any way to do that? Or I will have to change the URL whenever I go to the next sections?

Answer (score 0):

just simply use javascript and `require(['your_controller']);`

like:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(document.body.scrollTop == 500){
        require(['your_controller']);
    }
});
```

This will add your_controller.js to your page when you scroll down 500px from the top of the page. But still it may not be work in the way you expecting. I have never done such thing to load a controller, but according to your question. This will help you load the script file of your controller.

Comment: Let me test it. I will then reply back